# how to use Variables inside vlookup of Formula R1C1?

Tags: excel, vba, variables, vlookup

Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-1-" & NofRanks & "]>R4C3,RC[-4-" & NofRanks & "]/R2C3,0)"

I don't understand why it's giving me a syntax error. Can someone please help?

Here NofRanks is a variable-integer.

Comment: I believe the problem is the quotes around the comma (`","`) what happens if you remove them?

Comment: Try `"=VLOOKUP(RC1,'Basic Sheet'!C" & j & ":C6, 6,FALSE)"`

Comment: @RaymondWu Thank you, i wasted 6 hours working on this, should have had the brains to ask in the 1st place, i was running around in circles!!!

Comment: Selection.FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1,'Basic Sheet'!C" & j & ":C"&j+5&", 6,FALSE)"

if i try this, why am i getting error again?
what mistake am i making?

Comment: If you have trouble translating formula to vba, what you can do it make `Debug.Print` the string that you make and copy-paste the output in the immediate window to the cell formula bar and see if it works. Sometimes you might not even need to copy-paste as looking at the output will make you realise what are you passing to the `Formula` property. @MysticalDevices

Comment: Make sure you have space inbetween the variable, operator and strings. The lack of space might cause VBA to read it differently. @MysticalDevices